# how to get a custom scroll in firefox and IE?

Tags: css

I am using a custom scroll which works fine in chrome...but it does not work in Firefox or IE9.

This is the CSS:

```
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
    height: 1px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb    
{
    height: 1em;
    background: #ccc -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgb(240, 240, 240)), to(rgb(250, 250, 250)));  
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;  
} 

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment {
   background:url(../images/down.png) center no-repeat;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement
{
   background:url(../images/up.png) center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: @pacofvf: That's exactly what he's asking for.

Comment: @SLaks if you are right, you should edit the question to ask exactly that. I don't think that the OP knew that. I just wanted to point him in the right direction.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you want your scrollbar to look like? i can't see the images you listed in the code above.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That is a proprietary webkit property. There is no equivalent for FF or IE.

You can, however, do what you're looking for with jQuery.

http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

**Edit:** Uhhh.. there literally is no Firefox equivalent and the person asking the question literally must either use a javascript solution, or no solution at all. Downvotes won't change that.

Comment: is it so that this plugin is only applicable for fixed height container?

Comment: Anybody thinks Firefox will soon incorporate custom scrollbars? At least when CSS 4 will come out I hope?

Answer (score 4):

While Firefox doesn't currently have a way to change scrollbars (see [bug 77790](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790) for a *somewhat* related issue), Internet Explorer has had *limited* functionality since version 5.5 (only supports colors). For more information, read more about it at [MSDN's User Interface page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974092%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

***Note:** The syntax has not always been the same for changing scrollbar colors in IE, so if you're looking to support older versions (I believe 7 and under), you will have to use the old syntax as well.*

Comment: I'm always amazed what a forward thinking browser IE actually was. Sure, they were totally non-standard about it, but they had rotation, gradients, drop shadows, and several other neat features well before anyone else.

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski - Because they were doing things for themselves, not for the web. Other browsers did not exist at the time or only followed the standard.

Answer (score 1):

A much used solution is http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/
It supports most mayor browsers. Check the basic examples: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a [custom scrollbar library named SimpleScrollbar](https://github.com/buzinas/simple-scrollbar).

It does not depend on any other library/framework, and it's less than 1KB after gzip and minification.

It uses the native scroll, so there are no hacks, and the performance is awesome.

---

You only need to include the library in your page, and use the `ss-container` attribute in any div that you want to make scrollable. Live example:

```html
<link href="http://buzinas.github.io/simple-scrollbar/simple-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="height: 180px; width: 200px; display: inline-block;" ss-container>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<section style="height: 180px; width: 300px; display: inline-block;" ss-container>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
      <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?</p>
</section>
<!--[if IE 9]><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/classlist/2014.01.31/classList.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="http://buzinas.github.io/simple-scrollbar/simple-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
```

---

It works on all the modern browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, Edge), and on IE10 and IE11. You can also use it in IE9 by including a classList polyfill.

All Android, iOS and Windows Phone browsers are supported either.

Answer (score 0):

http://darsa.in/sly/ this is very lightweight easy to customize mobile friendly custom scrollbar. Check this example http://darsa.in/sly/examples/vertical.html

Answer (score 0):

It might be of interest:
Firefox 64 contains now at least the scrollbar-width and scrollbar-color option for the track and thumb of the scrollbar, cf. release notes and bug tracker here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1460109

Best wishes,
SG