# IE 10 does not display scrollbar in html

Tags: html, css

i have scrollbar like this in google chrome

[image]

but in IE 10, it display like this :

[image]

Comment: the `webkit-` prefix prevents IE from using the CSS

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9332786/2471423), it wont work on IE or FF.

They do however supply a link to use a jQuery work around. ([http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html)](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html)

Comment: Oh :(, but how can i show default scrollbar as full, not it is half cut

Comment: I think it's the `background-clip` property. But I'm not sure. @vir

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the scrollbar-xxx-color properties in IE10.

- scrollbar-track-color property

Specifies the color of the track element of a scroll bar.

CSS

```
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.blueScroll {
  scrollbar-highlight-color: aqua;
  scrollbar-face-color: blue;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: blue;
  border-color: blue;
}
.redScroll {
  scrollbar-highlight-color: bisque;
  scrollbar-face-color: red;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: red;
  border-color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="blueScroll">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
  <div class="redScroll">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
</body>
```

You can see the working demo here..[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KeqX4/)

For more info.. Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531160%28v=vs.85%29.aspx